# PHP Variable Posting 0 Into Database

Tags: php, html, forms, pdo

So i have this code which basically is used to update a record. It populates a form, the user makes the changes (or doesn't) clicks update and then it runs through this code. I've managed to get it all working, however the model field KEEPS replacing whatever was there with '0'. So if the model box contained 'Ford' when the user clicks update the model field will the equal '0' and i can't figure out why.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
//Run the UPDATE code right here please!!!
$vID2 = $_POST['hiddenVehicleID'];
$model2 = $_POST['model'];
$varient2 = $_POST['varient'];
$stockno2 = $_POST['stockno'];
$vinNo2 = $_POST['vinNo'];
$trans2 = $_POST['transmission'];
$cc2 = $_POST['cc'];
$colour2 = $_POST['colour'];
$delivery2 = $_POST['delivery'];

if (empty($_POSt['stock'])) {
    $stock2 = "N/A";
}
$stock2 = $_POST['stock'];

$status2 = $_POST['status'];
$customer2 = $_POST['customer'];

if (empty($_POST['tax'])) {
    $tax2 = "N/A";
}
$tax2 = $_POST['tax'];

$financeS2 = $_POST['financeSettlement'];
$finance2 = $_POST['finance'];
$comments2 = $_POST['comments'];
$orderNo2 = $_POST['orderNo'];
$editedBy2 = $user_id;
$dateAdded2 = $_POST['hiddenUpdate'];
$lastUpdated2 = date("m/d/y");
$progress2 = $_POST['progress'];

$sth = $salesConn->prepare('
    UPDATE `vehicleOrderForm` SET 
        `model` = :veh_model,
        `varient` = :veh_varient, 
        `stockno` = :veh_stockno, 
        `vinNo` = :veh_vinNo, 
        `transmission` = :veh_trans, 
        `cc` = :veh_cc, 
        `colour` = :veh_colour, 
        `delivery` = :veh_delivery, 
        `stock` = :veh_stock, 
        `status` = :veh_status, 
        `customer` = :veh_customer, 
        `tax` = :veh_tax, 
        `financeSettlement` = :veh_settlement, 
        `finance` = :veh_finance, 
        `comments` =:veh_comments, 
        `orderNo` = :veh_orderNo, 
        `editedBy` = :veh_edited, 
        `dateAdded` = :veh_added, 
        `lastUpdated` = :veh_updated, 
        `progress` = :veh_progress 
    WHERE `vehicleOrderForm`.`id` = :vID; ');


$sth->bindValue(':vID', $vID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_model', $model2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_varient', $varient2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_stockno', $stockno2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_vinNo', $vinNo2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_trans', $trans2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_cc', $cc2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_colour', $colour2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_delivery', $delivery2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_stock', $stock2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_status', $status2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_customer', $customer2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_tax', $tax2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_settlement', $financeS2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_finance', $finance2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_comments', $comments2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_orderNo', $orderNo2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_edited', $editedBy2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_added', $dateAdded2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_updated', $lastUpdated2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':veh_progress', $progress2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$sth->execute();
```

It doesn't post any errors and everything else works fine. I can't figure out why it won't post properly, I have turned error reporting on at the top of the page and it doesn't post any errors. It acts as if it runs properly.

This is how the model section of my form looks. I use a switch because i want the option to already be selected on a drop down menu so the user knows what model the car is currently set as.

```
                    <?php 
                switch ($model) {
                    case '3':
                        ?>
                        <div class="c">
                            <label for="vehicleModel">Vehicle Model:</label>
                            <select name="model" id="vehicleModel">
                                <option value="N/A">Please Select</option>
                                <option selected value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="ZS">ZS</option>
                                <option value="GS">GS</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                        break;

                    case 'ZS':
                        ?>
                        <div class="c">
                            <label for="vehicleModel">Vehicle Model:</label>
                            <select name="model" id="vehicleModel">
                                <option value="N/A">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option selected value="ZS">ZS</option>
                                <option value="GS">GS</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                        break;

                    case 'GS':
                        ?>
                        <div class="c">
                            <label for="vehicleModel">Vehicle Model:</label>
                            <select name="model" id="vehicleModel">
                                <option value="N/A">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="ZS">ZS</option>
                                <option selected value="GS">GS</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                        break;

                    default:
                        ?>
                        <div class="c">
                            <label for="vehicleModel">Vehicle Model:</label>
                            <select name="model" id="vehicleModel">
                                <option selected value="N/A">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="ZS">ZS</option>
                                <option value="GS">GS</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        break;
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Just FYI, that second script can really be simplified to just 1/4th of what it is if you check the value of `$model` just before printing `selected` on every single option

Comment: Also, in your developer tools / console log / var_dump($_POST) are you seeing all of the parameters of your submission going through?

Comment: `$sth->bindValue(':veh_model', $model2, PDO::PARAM_INT);` <-- You're binding it as an INT instead of STR

Comment: Generally this happens when you bind wrong as @aynber mentioned or when your db column is int and you are passing string.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, i must've copied the ID row for some stupid reason! @FedericoklezCulloca how would i reduce the amount of code i'm using? I currently check what the $model is and if it equals 'ZS' i use a certain code. I thought a switch was the best way, but i'm all ears because it takes AGES!

Comment: @BenSmith for example `<option <?php $model == '3' ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="3">3</option>`. Extrapolate for the other options ;) The default one might get tricky, though. Just don't have anything selected by default, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding as an integer instead of a string.

```
$sth->bindValue(':veh_model', $model2, **PDO::PARAM_INT**);
```